# Request is not created

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have created a wcf  client that makes a request to get the data.
When i made a call to service, the request itself not created.
I am sending all the header information to the service and it is not sending a request.
The request is using SOAP,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext- 1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    <VisSvcHeaders xmlns="http://dai.es.VisSvc/2010/svc">
        <packNGo>false</packNGo>
    </VisSvcHeaders>
    <wsa:Action>http://vissvc.esi.daimler.com/2010/svc/getData</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:From>
        <wsa:Address>Vis</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:From>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:795b9745-4867-4f05-af5a-  87704920a6dd</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
         <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To>https://vissvc.e.corpintra.net/VisSvcNative/DAIESIVisService</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6bf652ad-6f2e-4312-ae4f-5807c5f21e38">
            <wsu:Created>2014-02-19T08:41:48Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2014-02-19T08:46:48Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <getData xmlns="http://dai.esi.VisSvc/2010/svc">
        <part xmlns="">
            <number xmlns="http://dai.es.VisSvc/2010/bo">43</number>
            <referenceConfiguration xmlns="http://dai.esi.VisSvc/2010/bo">
                <lifecycle xmlns="">Rel</lifecycle>
            </referenceConfiguration>
            <mode xmlns="http://dai.es.VisSvc/2010/bo">open</mode>
        </part>
    </getData>
</soap:Body>
```

How can I send the request as this, and the code I am using is,

```
       ServiceReference2.ServicePortTypeClient svc = new     ServiceReference2.ServicePortTypeClient();
       WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://vissvc- test.e.intra.net/SvcNative/VisService");
       ServiceReference2.PartType part = new ServiceReference2.PartType();
       part.number = "43";        
       ServiceReference2.ResponseType res = svc.getData(part);
       Console.WriteLine(res);
```

This request of getData() is not sending or creating a request of this sort.

I am using .net c# 4.0.

Comment: what happens when you type service URL into a browser address bar? What response do you get from the server?

Comment: @Brian- when i type in the browser it automatically opens a WSDL. But there is a custom dll provided from the company side, after adding it,it is said that the request is automatically sent to service. But I am not able to see the request at all.

Comment: My intent was to get you to the WSDL ... that shows that the host is running, basically the first step in getting communication going. You can use that WSDL (plus some MS utilities) to generate the correct interface for consuming the web service

Comment: @Brian- so we should create a request on our own for communication? Earlier they used http web request.

Comment: No, use what you had before. If it worked before, and the WSDL page shows that communication is open, it should work again. If it's not, it's up to you to figure out why it's not working. What I've used in the past is Fiddler, a shareware product that sits between the client and host and listens for the messages passing. Fiddler will show you what the real messages are and what the reactions are from the host. That's what I'd try.